# Android Updating notification text causes memory usage

Tags: android, service, notifications, android-notifications, foregroundnotification

So I have a service with a foreground notification that is launched when the user navigates away from the activity.

I update this notification consistently every second with a String that has a time, but every update causes the memory usage to go up by at least 0.01 MB. Here's the code I'm using:

```
mNotiBuilder.setContentText(mBuilder.toString());
mNotiManager.notify(notificationId, mNotiBuilder.build());
```

I've tested that the string builder I'm using is not causing it.

I don't really know why this is happening, should I be even worried about it at all? I'm a stickler when it comes to resource usage so I'm trying to get this right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I wouldn't worry too much. Each time you build a new Notification, it will take some memory. Android probably doesn't run a garbage collection cycle as long as you have enough memory, meaning that old Notification will stay around for a while.

Comment: Alright, this is probably the right answer. The GC will save all of us.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing right... And I don't think you should be worried about it.
Just check [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/training/notify-user/managing.html)

You just need to use the same notification id to update your notification(without creating a new one).